# Not Returning ASCII characters when encrypting

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to write an encryption code using Python.  It encrypts but it does not use the ASCII characters and I am not sure why.  I am very new to python and would love some help

```
def encrypt(text, shift):

    cipher=""
    for char in range(len(text)):
        char = text[char]

        if (char.isupper()):
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + shift - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)

    return cipher
```

It is encrypting but not returning ASCII characters

Comment: Are you able to get all characters eg #$%%^^&&& within the encryption?

Answer (score 1):

The formula

```
enc = (char + shift - offset) % m + offset
```

implicitly defines an alphabet within whose boundaries the encryption takes place, i.e. a character within *this* alphabet is mapped to another character of *this* aphabet. For example, the uppercase letters have an offset of 65 and a modulus of 26 (number of characters in the alphabet). This defines the alphabet as the range between 65 (A) and 65 + 26 - 1 = 90 (Z). A character between incl. A and Z is *always* mapped to a character between incl. A and Z and *never* to a character *outside* the alphabet. The same applies to lowercase letters. For this reason:

```
print("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
print(encrypt("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5));
```

results in the output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde
```

If the special characters are also to be included, the range must be choosen accordingly, e.g. as a *contiguous* range between incl. 32 (Space) and incl. 126 (~). This corresponds to an offset of 32 and a modulus of 126 - 32 + 1 = 95 (number of characters in alphabet). The if-statement is no longer necessary because of the contiguous range, so that simply applies:

```
cipher += chr((ord(char) + shift - 32) % 95 + 32)
```

The following code:

```
print(" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~");
print(encrypt(" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~", 5));
```

then produces the output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ !"#$
```

which now also contains the special characters.